# .htaccess with WordPress - specific mod-rewrite rules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, s3-rewrite-rules

I have a "little problem" with .htaccess and WordPress and hope someone can give ma a hint to solve it.

I need a rewrite rule that catches the domain without "www." or "https/www." to be more specific it should route from example.com/*code* ( without http://www. ) to rewrite rule https://www.example.com/?productcode=*code*. I tried to put the rewrite rule bevor the WordPress .htaccess part and after but it all ended up with an error - I'm stuck

the standard .htaccess in WordPress:

```
My Wordpress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The Productcode is 1 to 7 digits long and contains only Characters 0-9 A-Z and a-z.
I used the [L] when i put the rewrite rule at the beginning of the rules.

The rewrite rule was inserted manually in WordPress for testing - which is not a good idea since it will be overwritten by WordPress, it will be later ( when I know the it works added via functions.php)

My rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^example\.com/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,7}$ https://www.example.com/productcode=$1 [L]
```

I understood that "^" is the beginning of the rule and excludes "www." or "https://www", then follows the domain and the code, which can be 1-7 digits long, which is then redirected to https://www.example.com/productcode=$1 and all of the other sites are not infected by by rule, or am I wrong?

Comment: You are wrong in apparently assuming that RewriteRule would match against a full URL. It matches against the _path_ component of the URL only. If you want to check on other stuff, like the host name, you need to use a RewriteCond to do that.